# Breadboard Software?

Tags: macos, mac, software-recommendation, software

I am learning how to do some beginner work with electronics, so I am looking for a breadboard.  Now I know I can go down the local RadShack and pick one up, but in doing so, I'll spend $20 on a board, another $10 on wires, and possibly more on electronics I need to duplicate the entire practice they want me to do in the book.

All in all I'm not willing to shove $50 to $100 on a breadboard and it's toys just to learn something on my own just yet.

I am looking for a Breadboard software package for the Mac, either it be universal or not.  Is there such a thing as this or am I stuck spending $100 on a breadboard, electronics, and a case to keep it all organized?

Answer (score 1):

### [iCircuit](http://icircuitapp.com)

[image]

> iCircuit is the easy to use electronic circuit simulator and designer - the perfect tool for students, hobbyists, and engineers.
>
> Its advanced simulation engine can handle both analog and digital circuits and features realtime always-on analysis. It is the perfect companion to students, hobbyists, and engineers.